# alternatives to window.open for IE 8 or higher

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

We have a requirement to open an external application in a new window and still having a handle to close it.

These are the limitations we are bound to:

1. We have to submit a GET request.
2. External URl doesn't want to give much control to the calling application. For eg- opening external aplication in an iframe is not allowed.
3. The calling application needs to close the external URL window based on when it receives a flag indication session is complete.

So far we have tried window.open with couple of twists and tweaks, but any solution does not work in IE 8 or higher.

We have a raised a ticket in microsoft forum, but just wanted to know, if there are any alternatives to window.open to achieve this.

System configuration:

Windows 7-64bit OS with IE 8.0.7601.17514 with 256 Cipher Strength.

The challenge unresolved is getting a handle and closing the new window opened.

The options we have tried:

Approach 1:

```
var handle = window.open("http://www.example.com/details.jspuser=test&age=20", "windowname");
handle.close();   // Here handle is coming as null.
```

Approach 2:

JavaScript:

```
   var target =  "windowname";
   var handle = window.open("about:blank",target);
   if(handle!= null) // here we are getting the handle object
   {
       document.getElementById('form1').target = target; // setting the target to Pop window
       document.getElementById('form1').submit();  // Now this will submit the form and send the GET request to pop up
       alert(handle.closed);  // Noticed that this line is giving "true", even though we have not closed the pop up
       handle.close(); // does not close the pop up window
   }
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" method="GET" action="http://www.example.com/details.jsp
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="20">
</form>
```

Workaround :

If we open the browser in protected mode: on this problem resolves.

Comment: Disable the popup blocker.

Comment: Most browsers only let `window.open` work when it's called from inside a click handler.

Comment: Try `showModalDialog` perhaps